# Select random row in MySQL with condition

Tags: mysql, random, row, conditional-statements, where-clause

I would like to know if it's possible to select random row with special condition...

I explain myself:

**select 3 row with attribut isTrue = 0 but in my 3 row i want one with isTrue = 1**

I've a table "reponse" like:

[Table Reponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD2Kr.jpg)

I would like to do something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM reponse 
WHERE isTrue = 0 (and one of row(isTrue = 1)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
```

I don't know if you realy understood what i want to do
PS: I'm french

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

(SELECT * FROM reponse WHERE isTrue = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) 
union all 
(SELECT * FROM reponse WHERE isTrue = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2) 
ORDER BY RAND()

Thank you very much Evgeny !!